# retrieving attribute in iframe

Tags: jsp, iframe, request, session-variables

I have problem in retrieving the request attributes in IFRAME.
the following are the snippets, in jsp1.jsp, i have 2 IFRAMES whose src are jsp2.jsp and jsp3.jsp .i would like to retrieve the request attributes in both the pages.Basically the attribute is an object of a class and some values were set for class variables in the jsp1.jsp page.I would like to share that object between these 3 pages. Inside the IFRAME i am getting null value for the attribute..I have tried both session.setAttribute and request.setAttribute

### jsp1.jsp

```
<td>
<%
Search beans=(Search)request.getAttribute("s");
session.setAttribute("s");
%>
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" tabIndex="-1" width="100%" height="100%"   
frameborder="0" src="jsp2.jsp"></iframe>
<iframe name="frame2" id="frame2" tabIndex="-1" width="100%" height="100%" 
frameborder="0" src="jsp3.jsp"></iframe>
</td>
```

### jsp2.jsp

```
Search beans = (Search)session.getAttribute("s");
if (beans != null) {
//process the bean
}
```

Could someone please let me know how to retrieve the set  Attribute. And also i can't pass it as an parameter to the jsp2.jsp since it is an object

Thanks
Priyam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML `<iframe>` basically instructs the webbrowser to send a **brand new** HTTP request on the given `src` URL and embed its response. It does not run within the request of the parent JSP page in the webserver. So passing objects as a request attribtue ain't going to work. The session will only work if it has already been established *before* you request the parent JSP page.

I do not understand why you're using an `<iframe>` this way. It's a very poor approach when the sole purpose is to include page fragments which reside at the same server as the parent page. The `<iframe>` is only useful whenever you want to embed **external** content in your webpage.

Replace them by server side includes like `<jsp:include>` and it'll work the way you initially want.

```
<jsp:include page="jsp2.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="jsp3.jsp" />
```

They'll be included within the very same HTTP request and thus have access to its attributes. The benefits are big. Your problem is instantly solved, the SEO will be greatly improved (the `<iframe>` content is namely not indexed as part of the parent page) and the User Experience also (more predictable and robust website behaviour whenever there are links and forms inside the `<iframe>`).